# Is $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{a})=0$ if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a}=0$?

Tags: vectors, tensors

Is $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{a})=0$ if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{a}=0$?
If so, how can I show it? I just got $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{a})=\frac{\partial }{\partial {{x}_{j}}}\frac{\partial {{a}_{i}}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{i}}$ and i'm stuck here. I should clarify that $\nabla \mathbf{a}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}\otimes {{\mathbf{e}}_{j}}=\frac{\partial {{a}_{i}}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{i}}}\otimes {{\mathbf{e}}_{j}}$. Also $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial {{x}_{k}}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{k}}}=\frac{\partial {{A}_{ij}}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{i}}}$ when
$\mathbf{A}={{A}_{ij}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{i}}}\otimes {{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{j}}}$ is a second order tensor.

Comment: @Surm I think $0$ here might refer to the zero function, or the zero vector field, not a function of field that happens to be $0$ at a given point.

Comment: @Arthur ah... so the question is: is the second derivative of a constant mapping always zero?

Comment: I'm refering to the gradient of a vector defined as $\nabla \mathbf{a}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}\otimes {{\mathbf{e}}_{j}}=\frac{\partial {{a}_{i}}}{\partial {{x}_{j}}}{{\mathbf{e}}_{\mathbf{i}}}\otimes {{\mathbf{e}}_{j}}$

Comment: @b,goddard The gradient of a vector is a tensor of rank 2.  So, indeed one can define $\nabla \vec a$.  In this case, the successive operations $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \vec a)=\nabla^2(\vec a)$ is identical to the vector Laplacian on $\vec a$.

Comment: @B.Goddard That is a problem with communicating on MSE.  Comments can be stale and the clutter can confuse future readers.  I'll delete mine in a moment.  -Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for instance
$a = (y^2, x^2, 0)$ satisfies
$$ div(a) = 0,$$
but
$$\Delta(a) = (2, 2, 0) \not= 0.$$